# Speed up rbindlist as .combine within foreach in R

Tags: r, foreach, data.table, rparallel, rbindlist

Consider the following piece of code runing on a windows OS with `doSNOW` package:

```
result.dt <- foreach(j = 1:nrow(keys), 
                    .combine = function(...) rbindlist(list(...)), 
                    .packages = c('data.table'), 
                    .multicombine = TRUE) %dopar% {
    data.select <- data[keys[j], on = colnames(keys)]
    foo(data.select)
}
```

`keys` is some `data.table` with around 2000 rows and `foo` is a function that runs decent amount of time (10s - 3m) and return a `data.table` with a single row.

When I turn on `.verbose = TRUE`, I can see the `foo` function for different cores running as expected (say 30m). However, after everything with `foreach` finishes, the code consumed another 30m (sometimes even longer) just to combine the 2000 `data.table`.

Another thing to notice, when `verbose = TRUE`, it always showed `numValues: .., numResults: .., stopped: FALSE` even if it was the end of the `foreach`. I was expecting to see `stopped: TRUE`.

Any idea to what can be wrong and how to improve the performance?

Comment: Let `foreach` return a list (by not specifying `.combine`) and do `result.dt <- rbindlist(result.dt)` afterwards? I believe your anonymous function might force a deep copy of all data.tables.

Comment: @Roland I tried that approach already but ran into the same thing.

Comment: Something is strange here. How many columns has that single-row data.table?

Comment: @Roland Only three.

Comment: `rbindlist` is instantaneous for 2000 1x3 data.tables. What happens if you change the last line of the loop to `as.data.frame(foo(data.select))`?

Comment: @Roland It showed the same behavior.

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of ideas. You'll need to provide a reproducible example for further help.

Comment: @Roland Thanks anyway. One more thing to notice is that the combination always happen at the end of everything. I thought it was supposed to happen every 100 iteration with `.multicombine = TRUE`

Comment: What makes you think that? I suspect it simply switches between use of `Reduce` and `do.call`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163880/discussion-between-chen-chen-and-roland).